# How to translate C++ char** to Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a C++ DLL:

```
int __stdcall Hello(int numFiles, char **inFiles)
```

and I don't know how to translate this char **.
I tried:

```
function Hello(numFiles: Integer; InFiles: PPChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'dll2.dll';
```

and then:

```
    Files: array of PChar;
begin
   SetLength(Files, 2);
   Files[0] := PChar('siema.jpg');
   Files[1] := PChar('siema2.jpg');

   c := Hello(2, @Files[0]);
```

but all I get is "Access violation"

Comment: Show the actual call to `Hello`. I don't see how you can possibly determine the correct value for `numFiles` inside `Compress`.

Comment: ...The first argument to `Hello` cannot be `Hello`. Post your *actual* code.

Comment: @hvd Yes, sorry, I copied it incorrectly (in parts). Now it's fine

Comment: c++ char usually is AnsiChar in Delphi (Delphi 2009+). Try use PAnsiChar, PPAnsiChar etc.

Comment: FWIW, if you must translate more of this kind of code, you may want to read [my article about such conversions](http://www.praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-convert.html).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, added to bookmarks for future reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the face of it, given the information in the question, your code seems basically fine. However, a rookie mistake, made by many beginners with interop, is to believe that a function's signature is enough to define the interface. It is not. For instance, a parameter of type `char**` could be used for many different things. So, to specify the information you must also specify the semantics of the parameters, not just the syntax.

Given

```
int __stdcall Hello(int numFiles, char **inFiles)
```

let us assume the following:

- The return value is an error code, with `0` indicating success.
- The first parameter is the number of files.
- The second parameter is an array of files, of length specified by the first parameter. Each element of the array is a C string, a pointer to a null-terminated array of 8 bit characters.

With those assumptions in place, I would write the code like this:

```
function Hello(numFiles: Integer; InFiles: PPAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'dll2.dll';
```

The function would be called like this:

```
var
  Files: array of PAnsiChar;
  retval: Integer;
....
SetLength(Files, 2);
Files[0] := PAnsiChar('siema.jpg');
Files[1] := PAnsiChar('siema2.jpg');
retval := Hello(Length(Files), PPAnsiChar(Files));
if retval <> 0 then
  ... handle error
```

You might prefer to write the final parameter as `@Files[0]` if you prefer. I prefer the cast because it allows me to pass an empty array even when range checking is enabled.

Note that I used `PAnsiChar` to match with `char*`. The `PChar` type is an alias to either `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar` depending on the Delphi version. It is better to be explicit.

Of course, my assumptions may be wrong. You should confirm them by consulting the library's documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. Works like a charm!